# Почему не грузится SVG на Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Я все сделал
1.скачал svg package
2.сделал импорт

но все равно выдает исключение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1229893/420098/edit))

Answer (score 2):

Судя по скриншотам, Вы для Flutter web используете [вот этот package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg), который только под iOS и Android.

Для работы с Web поищите на https://pub.dev SVG package с пометкой `WEB`.

Comment: Не хочу ничего утверждать, но в Flutter'e я думаю есть проблема. Почему то не загружаются картинки из инета хоть это image или svg, через network "не идет",  скачав, только сработало у меня

Comment: @Ramil Убедитесь, что вы находитесь на канале dev или beta и подберите пекедж как писал автор выше.

flutter channel dev